# Javascript how to clear interval after specific time

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
setInterval("FunctionA()", 1000);
```

Now how do I clear this interval after exactly 5 seconds so that I can achieve -

```
var i = setInterval("FunctionA()", 1000);
(After 5 seconds)
clearInterval(i);
```

Comment: `setInterval("FunctionA()", 1000)` is very much equivalent to `setInterval(FunctionA, 1000)`, but the latter does not involve an `eval` and is thus much more efficient.

Comment: @lanzz thanks for that, appreciate it

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do this using `setTimeout` function:

```
var i = setInterval(FunctionA ,1000);
setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( i ); }, 5000);
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not exact with short time intervals for example 40ms as Interval and 5000ms as timeout

Answer (score 17):

Using setTimeout to clearInterval is not an ideal solution.  It will work, but it will fire your setTimeout on each interval. This is ok if you're only clearing the interval, but might be bad if you're executing other code besides clearing the interval.  A better solution is to use a counter. If your interval fires every 1000ms/1sec, then you know if it fires 5 times it's been 5 seconds.  That's much cleaner.

```
count=0;
var x=setInterval(function(){
  // whatever code
  if(count >= 4) clearInterval(x);
  count++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: this does not work. x is not in the scope of the function

Comment: @daniel yes it is.

Comment: This answer is what I've been looking for. All you have to do is wrap the setInterval into a variable and call the clearInterval at how many counts as you want! Thanks @ironarm

Answer (score 2):

```
function intervalGap(){
    let no = 1;
    setInterval(function(){
    if(no < 11){
        console.log(no);
        no++;
    }else{
        clearInterval(this);
    }}, 500); // for every half second
}
intervalGap();
```