# set a timer in javascript when calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to set a timer in javascript in order to execute a function ever half a second in condition that if the time exceeded the two minutes the timer should stop:

my code :

```
  function InitialiseCountDown() {
    var x =setInterval(function(){
          CreateImage();
       },500);
          if(x== ? ) // what should i do here to make sure the two minites are done 
           {
         ClearInterval(x);
            }
     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363401/javascript-how-to-clear-interval-after-specific-time

Comment: Just as a side note: you should know that `setInterval` will most likely not run intervals in exactly 500ms. The real time between two calls depends on what else you are executing. So you should ask yourself if you want it to run for exactly two minutes, no matter how many iterations it will compute in that time (Olegas' answer), or if you want it run exactly 240 iterations no matter how much time it will take in the end (in this case you should use a counter that you increase by 500 every call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  try

```
 function InitialiseCountDown() {
    var x =setInterval(function(){
              CreateImage();
           },500);

    setTimeout(function( ) {
        clearInterval( x ); 
           },  2000*60);

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function InitialiseCountDown() {
    var start = +new Date();
    var x = setInterval(function(){
        CreateImage();
        if(+new Date() - start > 2 * 60 * 1000) {
            clearInterval(x);
        }
    },500);
}
```