# How to focus on dynamically added Input field in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

On button click I am showing a dialog which have input field. I want to autofocus in that input field. I'm using Material UI Component Dialog & OutlinedInput

```
const SearchIdDialog: React.FC = () => {
  const [openSearchId, setOpenSearchId] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  }, [openSearchId]);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenSearchId(false);
  };

  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Tooltip title="Click to search">
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            setOpenSearchId(true);
          }}
        >
          Search
        </Button>
      </Tooltip>

      <BootstrapDialog
        onClose={handleClose}
        open={openSearchId}
      >
        <SearchStyle
          inputRef={inputRef}
        />
      </BootstrapDialog>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have tried autoFocus prop but its failing. How to wait for input field to render input field first and then focusing it ?

Note: inputRef is used instead of ref because its a mui component which need inputRef.
If I use setTimeOut in useEffect and waits for 1 sec and then focus - it works. But I want it naturally.

Sandbox link- https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-f6hg5y?file=/src/SearchIdDialog.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `autofocus` is not working, then you can try with `setTimeout`.

What I did was to check if `openSearchId` is `true`
[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-5oipod?file=/src/SearchIdDialog.tsx)

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (openSearchId) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        inputRef.current?.focus();
        console.log("focused");
      }, 300);
    }
  }, [openSearchId]);
```

Does this work for you? You can change the millis of course.

Comment: Yes this is the only workaround which is working for me

Answer (score 1):

To autofocus on textfield whenever dialog box opens, you can use `autoFocus` props. It is working. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-xer6et)

Comment: Yaa, its working in Sandbox but not on localhost. Only solution which is working for me to add setTimeout in useEffect

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your BootstrapDialog componnet in conditional rendering. Something like:

```
{openSearchId &&
  <BootstrapDialog
    onClose={handleClose}
    open={openSearchId}
  >
    <SearchStyle
      inputRef={inputRef}
    />
  </BootstrapDialog>
 }
```

Like this autofocus will be triggered right when you open your dialog.

Comment: No, It didn't work @Milos Pavlovic

Comment: @Maddy8381 can you create a simple codesandbox?

Comment: Sure. Will add it in 10 mins

Comment: Then  you are probably gonna need useEffect with `inputRef.current` as dependency, and inside effect you just check if it is defined, and if it is then programmatically set focus through ref.

Comment: @Apostolos added sandbox link to question

Comment: In provided codesandbox it is working just by adding `autoFocus` prop to `<SearchStyle/>` element, no need to use ref. But if you still find it not working, then move useEffect callback in setTimeout and put delay for 100ms.

Comment: @MilosPavlovic. Yes, useEffect with setTimeOut is the only thing which is working for me. autoFocus is not working locally.

Answer (score 0):

First do this:

It calls the focus method after the input element is rendered.

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  }, [inputRef.current]);
```

If it did not work, try using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

```
  React.useEffect(()=> {
    const {current} = inputRef 
    
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (current != document.activeElement) {
           current.focus()
        } else {
          clearInterval(interval)
        }
   }, 3000)
    
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
    
  }, [openSearchId]);
```

```
 React.useEffect(()=> {
    const {current} = inputRef 
    
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (current != document.activeElement) {
           current.focus()
        } else {
          clearTimeout(timeout)
        }
    }, 3000)
    
    return () => clearTimeout(interval)
    
  }, [openSearchId]);
```

You probably need to restrict the number of times setInterval is called.

[Javascript how to clear interval after specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363401/javascript-how-to-clear-interval-after-specific-time)

Comment: Its not working for me @mahan